# XCode 4.3 Text from clipboard automatically in TextView by entering

Tags: xcode, text, view, clipboard, simulator

I don't find some information about the clipboard on the iPhone simulator and iPhone devices...
I have a textView and when I entered the textView I want see the text which is in clipboard.
I hope that somebody can help me.

Best Regards
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps look at [UIPasteboard Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)