# read text from clipboard and print it to console

Tags: objective-c, macos, console, clipboard

I am trying to write a code with objective-C in Xcode to read a text from clipboard and print it to console I have some trouble. with that. I would appreciate if you can help me to write this code.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 4.3 Text from clipboard automatically in TextView by entering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364142/xcode-4-3-text-from-clipboard-automatically-in-textview-by-entering)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, and not a programming school either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UIPasteboard` class from `UIKit` framework.

Apple doc says

> *The UIPasteboard class provides pasteboards: protected areas for sharing data within an app or between apps. The class offers methods
>   for writing and reading items of data to and from a pasteboard.*

for further reference [apple doc link 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html),
[link 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/index.html)

add this method in your viewcontroller and call it.

```
-(void)printClipboardContent{

    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *string = pasteboard.string;
    Nslog (@"clipboard text :%@",string);


}
```

Comment: I wrote the code but I received these errors the first error is in the first line under pasteboard it suggests if it is pClipboard . and the second error is in second line for undeclared identifier for paste board I put the image of my code in my post

Comment: Why did you put it on your main method

Comment: where should I put it ?

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: `UIPasteboard` doesn't exist on OS X.